# SharePoint 2010 - Event Receiver - Redirect URL not working

Tags: sharepoint, event-receiver

I have a problem with an event receiver, I created in Visual Studio.
In a special case, I want to redirect to a site. But the event receiver is showing only the error page with the error "An event receiver has canceled the request."
This message I can modify with the properties.ErrorMessage property, but I want to redirect and NO error message!
Here's my code:

```
if (NoErrors == false)
{

                    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
                    properties.RedirectUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(properties.WebUrl, @"MyEditForm.aspx?"
                                            + "Mode=Upload"
                                            + "&CheckInComment="
                                            + "&ID=" + properties.ListItem.ID
                                            + "&RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSuppliers%2FLists%2FDocument%20Center"
                                            + "&IsDlg=1"
                                            + "&ContentTypeId=" + properties.ListItem.ContentType.Id
                                            + "&IsDlg=1"
                                            + "&error=" + AllErrorsText);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Solution: Use a relative URL and no special characters in the error variable "AllErrorsText".

```
string TestUrl = "MyEditForm.aspx?"
                 + "Mode=Upload"
                 + "&CheckInComment="
                 + "&ID=" + properties.ListItem.ID
                 + "&RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSuppliers%2FLists%2FDocument%20Center"
                 + "&IsDlg=1"
                 + "&ContentTypeId=" + properties.ListItem.ContentType.Id
                 + "&IsDlg=1"
                 + "&error=" + AllErrorsTextUrl;
properties.RedirectUrl = TestUrl;
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
```

Comment: Ok, I figured it out myself. I had to use a relative URL and there was a mistake in my error variable - see my edit in the previous posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:

Use a relative URL and no special characters in the error variable "AllErrorsText".

```
    string TestUrl = "MyEditForm.aspx?"
                 + "Mode=Upload"
                 + "&CheckInComment="
                 + "&ID=" + properties.ListItem.ID
                 + "&RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSuppliers%2FLists%2FDocument%20Center"
                 + "&IsDlg=1"
                 + "&ContentTypeId=" + properties.ListItem.ContentType.Id
                 + "&IsDlg=1"
                 + "&error=" + AllErrorsTextUrl;
properties.RedirectUrl = TestUrl;
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
```